# ActiveRecord::Relation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Error from Rails, does this make sense to you?

```
<%= @permission.inspect %> outputs: [#<Permission project_id: 3, role_id: 2, user_id: 13>]

<%= Role.find(@permission.role_id) %>

undefined method `role_id' for [#<Permission project_id: 3, role_id: 2, user_id: 13>]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

This doesn't work either for some reason: `@permission.role.name`

Any Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@permissions` is a collection (Array). Try `@permissions.first.role_id`

Comment: Thanks. but permission should never return more than one record. Is there a way to obtain the var in Rails to specifiy it's not a collection but a single record? Right now I have: @permission = Permission.where(["user_id = ? AND project_id = ?", @user.id, @project.id])   thanks

Comment: Yes, in that case, as Shingara has said, `@permission = Permission.where(["user_id = ? AND project_id = ?", @user.id, @project.id]).first`. This will either return the permission object, or nil if no matching rows are found.

Answer (score 2):

@permission is an Array so you need iterate on it

```
<% @permission.each do |perm| %>
  <%= Role.find(perm.role_id) %>
<% end %>
```

If you want only one @permission return :

```
@permission = Permission.where(["user_id = ? AND project_id = ?", @user.id, @project.id]).first
```

Comment: Thanks. but permission should never return more than one record. Is there a way to obtain the var in Rails to specifiy it's not a collection but a single record? Right now I have: @permission = Permission.where(["user_id = ? AND project_id = ?", @user.id, @project.id])   thanks

Comment: use @permission = Permission.where(["user_id = ? AND project_id = ?", @user.id, @project.id]).first

Comment: Thanks... If there is only 1 matching result in the DB, will it return an array? Or is it always an array?

Comment: it's return nil or your object no anymore Array